# PHP SSH2 exec "$"

Tags: php, ssh, exec

i am wondering how i can run command from GET in PHP...
here is my code:

```
<?php
$msg = $_GET['msg'];
echo "$msg test";
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
if(!($con = ssh2_connect("ip", 22))){
    echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n";
} else {
    // try to authenticate with username root, password secretpassword
    if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, "root", "password")) {
        echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
    } else {
        // allright, we're in!

        echo "okay: logged in...\n";


        // execute a command
       if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, 'wall echo $msg'))) {

            echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
        } else {
            // collect returning data from command
            stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
            $data = "";
            while ($buf = fread($stream,4096)) {
                $data .= $buf;
            }
            fclose($stream);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

So, it wont wall what i say in ?msg= ... it just write blank, but when i echo $msg (like i did it on the top of code) it writes normally, do you guys know where is problem? i already tried "echo $msg" and \"echo $msh\" but same thing... thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a GET variable to an `ssh2_exec()` is probably a huge security issue. But disregarding that, single quotes ignore variables - you need double quotes for that.

In other words: change this

```
if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, 'wall echo $msg'))) {
```

to this

```
if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "wall echo $msg"))) {
```

However, I suspect that you're trying to use `echo` as a PHP construct, and you're only really interested in the `$msg` variable. In that case, you can just do

```
if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "wall $msg"))) {
```

or

```
if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, 'wall ' . $msg))) {
```

Comment: @McFilip for security use `'wall ' . escapeshellarg($msg)`