# PHP variable in ssh2_exec command

Tags: php, ssh, ssh2-exec

i have a problem with putting a variable with an IP address into a ssh2 command.

```
$somestring = 'ebtables -t filter -A FIREWALL -p IPv4 --ip-src '.$newifaceaddr.' --ip-proto tcp --ip-dport 22 -j ACCEPT';
$somevar = ssh2_exec($connection, $somestring);
```

Command works but not fully.
Expected result is "`-p IPv4 --ip-src 192.168.1.247 --ip-proto tcp --ip-dport 22 -j ACCEPT`", but what i get is "`-p IPv4 --ip-src 192.168.1.247 -j CONTINUE`
"

Funny thing is that if i write command as a string without variable like this "`ebtables -t filter -A FIREWALL -p IPv4 --ip-src 192.168.1.247 --ip-proto tcp --ip-dport 22 -j ACCEPT`" it works perfectly. And when i print one with a variable and one without the output is the same, so i dont know whats the problem with.

I tried this [PHP SSH2 exec "$"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30221695/php-ssh2-exec) and its not helping and many other things. plx halp :<

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that when i got data of IP from SSH2 via ssh2_exec, last character of string was some blank character that i had to remove using `$newifaceaddr = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $newifaceaddr);`

After that everything worked proparly.